# How to make the validation(only accepts alphanumeric) global for my model in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am currently new in ruby on rails and I have gem called rails admin. I want the validation not repeatable, i want it to save in one method and make it global so that in my model I can call the validation format.

I added a def in my application controller and inside of it i declare it as global but when I type special characters, it will be add.

Note: My validation is only allowed alphanumeric or underscore..

Expected Output: It wont add unless the input is alphanumeric or underscore

Question: Is my global variable wrong? How could I make a global variable so that I will just call it

**Model**

```
class ActivityType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :activities

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 },
                           :uniqueness => true,
                           format: { with: /\A[\w\_]+\z/ }
  validates :description, presence: true,
                         format: { with: /\A[\w]+\z/ }

end
```

**RegexValidations**

```
 module RegexValidations
  def self.alphanumeric_underscore
    { with: /\A[\w\_]+\z/ }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Validation are done at model level for their respective attributes.
- Defining methods in application_controller doesn't make it global, but accessible to all controllers inheriting from it.

Your model validation `validates` should be enough to validate format of the string in column.

Edit/Improvisation:

If you want to make the regex dry/not repeat for every model. Create a module in your `lib` folder say:

```
module RegexValidations
  def self.alphanumeric_underscore
    { with: /\A[\w\_]+\z/ }
  end
end
```

And in your model include it and say:

```
include RegexValidations
validates :description, presence: true, format: RegexValidations.alphanumeric_underscore
```

This way you can write multiple regex in one file and use it in every model keeping it DRY.
PS: unfortunately i couldn't test it..but it should work. Let me know if you encounter any error.

Comment: If you do `RegexValidations.alphanumeric_underscore`, you don't need to also include it.

Comment: I created new file called regexvalidations.rb, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, create a file named `regex_validations.rb` and maybe @Sergio Tulentsev is correct. Try without including it first.

Comment: @Angel, nope, create `regex_validations.rb` and put it in `/lib` folder. then follow my answer.

Comment: Sir @Md.FarhanMemon Right now, im not doing it.. I'll do the other module.. After this I'll inform you :)

Comment: sure buddy.. :)

Comment: if you have put the file in `lib` folder, you can use it the way shown in my answer. Not `including` the file in model will also work.

Comment: I tried to change format: { with: /\A[\w\_]+\z/ } into format: :alphanumeric_underscore but it gives me an error "check_options_validaty: A regular expression or a proc or lambda must be supplied as :with "

Comment: it should be like this `format: RegexValidations.alphanumeric_underscore`

Comment: I transfer my RegexValidations into lib.. and I also call like you suggestion above in my user.rb.. gives me an uninitialized User:RegexValidations

Comment: i see, did u include the file? if not then do it and see if error is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143747/discussion-between-angel-and-md-farhan-memon).

Comment: what do you mean include the file? Include my regexvalidation into my userfile? How?

Comment: write this line in your model, above validation `include RegexValidations`